# What is Noreferrer?

Tags: seo, technical-seo

I heard the term 'Noreferrer' while reading articles about links on the internet. I didn't get much information about this term. What exactly is this term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is noreferrer:**

Simply, if site a is in an article, site b, analytics, etc. If he uses the noreferrer definition when connecting to site b, he cannot see where the visitor is coming from. The reference source will be retained.

**When and why to use noreferrer:**

It can be used in external links, on sites that you do not want to appear as a reference, and for any purpose, just because you asked for it. Site owners can visit your site at least curiously in the reports you will submit as a reference, you should not forget that you have blocked this with this tag.